# Users higher than sessions? (Filtered by a dataLayer firing blog topic)

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We fire the blog topic into the dataLayer.

Example: https://www.theukdomain.uk/de-clutter-your-digital-office-to-strengthen-cyber-security/ fires the topic 'Keep It Legal' into the dataLayer which is then reported on in Google Analytics using a Custom Dimension (via hit scope).

However when analysing the stats; pageviews and users seems correct whilst unique pageviews and sessions doesn't. For example month to date we have the following:

Pageviews: 5,762
Unique Pageviews: 126
Users: 4,203
Sessions: 91

How can we have 91 sessions but 4,203 users and only 126 unique pageviews? Am I missing something? Is this due to the scope being set to hit rather than session or user?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related by rather related to analytics on the google analytics website probably better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the pageview 2 times to the same Analytics Property for each page displayed. Surely this means that you are collecting inconsistent data.